# How to make generic linq expression even more "generic"

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have the following class with an expression property:

```
public class ClassWithExpression
{
    public Expression<Func<SomeAbstractBaseClass, object>> SomeExpression { get; set; }
}
```

I need an expression to be able to handle all sub-classes of `SomeAbstractBaseClass` and all types of property selectors (int, string, decimal, etc). Eventually, the expression will be passed to a linq extension method like `OrderBy`. As it stands, it locks me into properties that appear on the base class only. The `object` prop selector is problematic when trying to pass in anything but a string prop.

I'd be okay with something like...

```
public class ClassWithExpression
{
    public Expression SomeExpression { get; set; }
}
```

... but nothing enforces that the expression is based on a sub-class of `SomeAbstractBaseClass`. Also, I'm not sure how I would pass an expression like that into the OrderBy extension method.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's a complete change of direction. :)

**EDIT:**

Sorry I didn't mention it earlier, but I can't use generics to solve this problem. Unfortunately, I don't know the types at compile-time.

Comment: Ah, well, if you don't know the types at compile time, then you can't really take advantage of strong typing, can you? You'll have to make do with the base class (or object), I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, that's getting clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure if it fits with what you're trying to do, but you may may to look into [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

Comment: I changed directions completely. I wish I could delete the question, but you guys already answered it. :)

Comment: No worries. If the open question is really bothering you, you can add your own answer and accept it, or flag it for moderator attention to get it closed

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic type constraint:

```
public class ClassWithExpression<T> where T : SomeAbstractBaseClass
{
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> SomeExpression { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention it earlier, but I don't know the types at compile-time, so I can't use generics. Otherwise, your answer would have been right on target.

Comment: @Byron: Sorry, what?  You don't know the types at compile-time, but you want them to be verified at compile-time?  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Nothing good, I can promise you that. I've decided to back way up and come at the problem from another direction. What I was trying to do was good ole fashioned "impossible".

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
private Expression<Func<SomeAbstractBaseClass, object>> SomeExpression;

public void SetExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    where T : SomeAbstractBaseClass
{
    SomeExpresssion = expression;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention it earlier, but I don't know the types at compile-time, so I can't use generics. Otherwise, your answer would have been right on target.